# Will different machine installed Android app (via Android Studio) get a different signature?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-signing

I have an old app that I've written for personal use only, and never made as release to the Play Store. I installed it to my phone via Android Studio using run app command.

Many years later I want to modify the app, I try to pick up the app and run it again, this time using a different computer. I get the error saying:

*"Installation failed since the device already has an application with the same package but a different signature. In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application."*

I definitely don't want to uninstall my app, this would cause me lost all the data I've entered to it. So I want to ask that isn't the debug keystore used by Android Studio to install app on device would create app of the same signature? Why it would be different? Is a different machine caused this issue? Thank you very much!

Comment: sorry, but i think, you can't resolve it. You should uninstall application and install it again, if you want update. May be you can find method to ignore signature? or create backup application?

Comment: Yes different systems have different debug signatures. You need to uninstall existing app and install from the new computer

Comment: Thanks Georgiy and Jinson, that's unfortunate :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you were using your debug certificate when you originally installed the app.  This is unique to each machine when you install Android Studio.

You can copy the debug certificate from your old machine to your new one.

The file is located in your `[userhome]\.android\debug.keystore`

Comment: The default expiration time for those keystores is 365 days AFAIK, unless the OP created the keystore themselves and set a longer validity time.

Comment: Thank you CodeChimp, this makes sense to me. But unfortunately I've already formatted my computer and re-installed. So there's no hope I can update my app without reinstalling it?

Comment: If you don't have the keystore and/or it expired you're out of luck. Unless your device is rooted and you can copy the data off of it before uninstalling/reinstalling it's unlikely you'll be able to save the data.

Comment: @Michael just checked my debug.keystore which was created in 2014 and it has an expiry of 2044 so seems like the default expiry has changed as I didn't create this myself.  Maybe earlier Android Studio install's created shorter expiry dates.